# How to determine IP and Port in random proxy script for curl?

Tags: proxy, curl

I have a random IP script for `curl` but I don't know how to use port for same random script:

```
function curl_get($kix) 
{
 $ips = array(
  '85.10.230.132',
  '88.198.242.9',
  '88.198.242.10',
  '88.198.242.11',
  '88.198.242.12',
  '88.198.242.13',
  '88.198.242.14',
    );
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $kix);
 @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ips[rand(0, count($ips)-1)]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
 $html = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $html;
}
```

You can see here I have mentioned the IP, but I don't know how to mention port for those IPs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read PHP Curl module documentation.

Answer (score 0):

These are interfaces. Interfaces can be by name or ip (i.e. eth0). You don't specify a port.